# give permission to /var/www

Tags: permissions, directory

When I write this to give permission to www directory:

```
zeb@zeb-Lenovo-B570:/var$ chmod 251 www/
zeb@zeb-Lenovo-B570:/var/www$ ls
```

Its gives error:

```
ls: cannot open directory .: Permission denied
```

I want to give permission to www folder so that I put my .php file here.

Help ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use

```
`sudo chmod 755 /path/your/folder`
```

provide your password

or use this for assigning permissions recursively for sub directories.

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /pat/your/folder
```

or open nautilus with permission by

```
sudo nautilus
```

and go to your desired folder ,right click on it and finally change its permissions as per your need.

to see permission allowed use

```
ls -l
```

it will show permissions of all the folders in Working Directory.

Comment: I got this. But In www folder how I give permission to PHP_Work directory in which I save .php files.

Comment: then use chmod -r 777 /path/to/folder instead , for giving permissions to subdirectories recursively or use 755, try both am not damn sure..

Comment: priviously used 251 is for allowing –w-r-x–x , and 777 will give read and write permission to everyone.

Comment: I write this , it work well:                                 zeb@zeb-Lenovo-B570:/var$ sudo chmod -R 775 www

Comment: if it solved your problem , accept it as an answer for future reference for others.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
sudo chmod 755 /var/www/
```

sudo gives you administrative permission as /var is under root directory.

Comment: when I write this: zeb@zeb-Lenovo-B570:~$ sudo chmod 755 /var/www/
It's not give permission to create new directory in it

Comment: Right now root is the owner of /var/www directory. Change the ownership of that directory to your user account by following command **sudo chown -R "YOUR_USER_ACCOUNT" /var/www**. After that you have all the permission over that directory.